# SSH reverse tunnel werdness: one extra tunnel

Tags: ssh

I have three devices, `school`, `home` and `portable`. I will hereon refer to them as S, H, and P. I want to be able to use P to run command and fetch files on H through the internet, but `home` has no public ip.

Now, S does have a public ip, ssh, and an exposed port 22. I can tunnel to S from anywhere. However, when I run

```
ssh -R 53469:localhost:22 school
```

at home (53469 is just a random unused port), and then

```
ssh school -p 53469
```

I am not able to connect: only port 22 is exposed at school.

So what I ended up doing was some sort of double-tunneling, using school as some sort of a rendezvous point. At home, I ran the reverse-tunneling command above. Then I used portable to tunnel to school, and then tunnel home via `localhost:53469`. Then this weird thing happens:

After running (on portable)

```
ssh school -p 22
```

and then

```
ssh localhost -p 53469
```

in the tunneled session, I end up back in school.

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> the first time gets me back to home (which is where I want to be). The second time gets me to school again. The third time returns me to portable.

What is happening here? Am I running some sort of script that tunnels me for the third, extra time?

Here's the `lsb_release` information:

**Home**

```
me@home:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.10
Release:    16.10
Codename:   yakkety
```

**School**

```
me@school:~>lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-5.0-amd64:core-5.0-noarch:desktop-5.0-amd64:desktop-5.0-noarch:imaging-5.0-amd64:imaging-5.0-noarch:languages-5.0-amd64:languages-5.0-noarch
Distributor ID: openSUSE project
Description:    openSUSE Leap 42.3
Release:    42.3
Codename:   n/a
```